# IIS Angular 7 page not loading images after upgrade to Angular 7 from 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, iis, webpack, upgrade

After upgrading Angular from 6 to 7 images that are being referenced in css with the rule `background-image: url('../../../../../assets/icons/T04_24_edit.svg')` are now being dumped directly into the dist folder when building for prod.

This is the dist folder:

[image]

And then my browser doesn't know how to load those svg's because IIS looks for them inside wwwrooot instead of dist:
[image]

[image]

This looks like some kind of optimization from the new Angular 7 build.

Is there any way I can disable this and revert to the Angular 6 way of using the path specified for images and not doing shady optimizations under the hood ?

Answer (score 0):

To place static assets in dist folder, which is created after production build - you need add appropriate path to `projects.your-project-name.architect.build.options.assets` in `angular.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what made it work was changing the url in the scss files from `background-image: url('../../../../../assets/icons/T04_24_edit.svg')` to `background-image: url('/assets/icons/T04_24_edit.svg')`